# Python unicode list weirdness

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I am having trouble with Python unicode strings. When I print a unicode string, Python is showing the unicode-only characters correctly, but when this string is inside a list, Python is converting these same characters to a strange code.

Here are the example codes:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s = 'São Paulo'
print s
>>São Paulo
```

OK!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
l = ['São Paulo']
print l
>>['S\xc3\xa3o Paulo']
```

Not OK... isn't showing a properly formatted unicode string.

Comment: You have `repr()` debug output. All Python containers use that to show the contents. This is *normal behaviour*. For the record, you have *byte strings*, containing data encoded to UTF-8. To get unicode strings, you'd have to *decode* or use the `u'..'` prefix. You still will get debugging output if you have `unicode` objects in a list though.

Comment: This behavior is changed in python 3, where the default string encoding has changed to unicode.

Answer (score 1):

`__str__` on a **container** (which is what `print` implicitly uses) always shows the `__repr__` of the **items** -- really inevitable to avoid ambiguity in corner cases, if you stop to think about it.

To work around that I recommend defining your own print-like function, rather than messing with either the container or the item classes.  This will inevitably produce potential ambiguity, but maybe you can live with it.

E.g:

```
def showstr(s):
    if "'" in s:
        delim = '"'
    else:
        delim = "'"
    return delim + s + delim

def showlist(l):
    result = []
    for x in l: 
        result.append(showstr(x))
    return '[' + ', '.join(result) + ']'
```

This has several potential ambiguities (and doesn't deal with lists containing both strings and other types of items, nor with strings containing both kinds of delimiters) but printing `showlist(l)` rather than directly `l` can be a start towards the "prettier for you" output you appear to be looking for.

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you guys, specially Alex Martelli!

Comment: @JohannGomes, you're welcome, but remember to **accept** an answer that's helped you (click the checkmark outline to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

`print` calls `str` on whatever it prints, however, `str(<iterable>)` will call `repr` on the elements of the container.